# Recaptcha V3 : ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, grecaptcha

We have been using recaptcha V3 for ours sites since last 6 months.
But since last week we are facing ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type.
I double checked and confirmed that the keytype is V3 in google recaptcha console.I created new V3 keys and checked.But that too didnt work.
Any idea on how to solve this problem?